# IF statement not reading the values properly

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I wrote an IF statement that's supposed to update  certain values within the same row based on certain codes. However, when the if statements reads my cell, its not assigning the proper logic. I have tried converting the column to numbers, to general, and vice versa and it still doesn't work. For example, value 309 should default to "CHECK" but it gets caught in the first if statement, why is that happening? PS-I have also tried getting rid of the "" around the numbers and it doesn't work.

[image]

```
Set rngVis = ws.Range("I2:I" & Lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each c In rngVis
    If c.Offset(0, 0).Value = "302" Or "304" Or "305" Or c.Offset(0, 0).Value = vbNullString Then
        c.Offset(0, 19).Value = "IAG-RoR"
        c.Offset(0, 25).Value = "BAD"
        c.EntireRow.Columns("A:AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 0).Value = "303" Or "306" Or "307" Or "310" Then
        'Do nothing'
    Else
        c.Offset(0, 19).Value = "CHECK"
        c.Offset(0, 25).Value = "CHECK"
        c.EntireRow.Columns("A:AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 28
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: `a = b or c` is *not* equivalent to `a = b or a = c`

Comment: ahhhh got it!
If c.Offset(0, 0).Value = "302" Or c.Offset(0, 0).Value = "304" Or c.Offset(0, 0).Value = "305"..... and so on!

Comment: @Socramvm a ```Select Case``` statement might also fit your needs, where ```Case a Or b Or c``` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `If/ElseIf/Else` you should use `Select Case`.

That will simplify things and avoid repitition.

```
    Set rngVis = ws.Range("I2:I" & Lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For Each c In rngVis
        Select Case c.Value
            Case "302", "304", "305", vbNullString
                c.Offset(0, 19).Value = "IAG-RoR"
                c.Offset(0, 25).Value = "BAD"
                c.EntireRow.Columns("A:AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Case "303", "306", "307", "310"
                'Do nothing'
            Case Else
                c.Offset(0, 19).Value = "CHECK"
                c.Offset(0, 25).Value = "CHECK"
                c.EntireRow.Columns("A:AG").Interior.ColorIndex = 28
        End Select
    Next c
```